# count of column_1 values for every distinct value in column_2 based on a given condition using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like,

```
date_1 | date_2
2018-12-08 | 2018-12-07
2018-12-09 | 2018-12-07
2018-12-13 | 2018-12-07
2018-12-16 | 2018-12-07
2018-12-14 | 2018-12-09
```

The output table should look like,

```
date_2 | count_of_date_1_after_date_2
2018-12-07 | 5
2018-12-09 | 3
```

I want the counts of `date_1` 'after' `date_2`.

I tried and came up with this answer but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. Is there a better way to do this?

```
WITH

sample_table AS (
  SELECT DATE('2018-12-08') AS date_1, DATE('2018-12-07') AS date_2, 'AAA' as uid UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2018-12-09') AS date_1, DATE('2018-12-07') AS date_2, 'AAA' as uid  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2018-12-13') AS date_1, DATE('2018-12-07') AS date_2, 'AAA' as uid  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2018-12-16') AS date_1, DATE('2018-12-07') AS date_2, 'AAA' as uid  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2018-12-14') AS date_1, DATE('2018-12-09') AS date_2, 'AAA' as uid 
),

distinct_date_2 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT(date_2) AS distinct_date, uid FROM sample_table
)


SELECT distinct_date, COUNTIF(date_1 > distinct_date)
FROM sample_table
LEFT JOIN distinct_date_2
USING (uid)
GROUP BY distinct_date
ORDER BY distinct_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date_2,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t.arr date_1 WHERE date_1 > date_2) AS count_of_date_1_after_date_2
FROM (
  SELECT date_2, ANY_VALUE(arr) arr
  FROM (
    SELECT date_2, ARRAY_AGG(date_1) OVER() arr
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ) 
  GROUP BY date_2
) t
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-12-08' date_1, DATE '2018-12-07' date_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-12-09', '2018-12-07' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-12-13', '2018-12-07' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-12-16', '2018-12-07' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-12-14', '2018-12-09' 
)
SELECT date_2,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t.arr date_1 WHERE date_1 > date_2) AS count_of_date_1_after_date_2
FROM (
  SELECT date_2, ANY_VALUE(arr) arr
  FROM (
    SELECT date_2, ARRAY_AGG(date_1) OVER() arr
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ) 
  GROUP BY date_2
) t
```

with result

```
Row     date_2          count_of_date_1_after_date_2     
1       2018-12-07      5    
2       2018-12-09      3
```

Comment: I want the count of dates in column `date_1` that are greater than the two distinct dates (2018-12-07, 2018-12-09) in column `date_2`. The result I am expecting is,
a count of 5 for 2018-12-07 and a count of 3 for 2018-12-09

Comment: got it. see updated answer. is it better or not? at least it avoids JOINs :o)

Comment: thanks for confirming. do you see any signs of it being "better"? like performance with or something else? can you share if any? :o)